# Login Database Failed

Tags: php, authentication, phpmyadmin, registration

I found a login tutorial (forget the URL) and I am making it into a game via PHP and HTML, but for users to be able to play they have to login. When I visited my [webpage](http://medievaltvg.freeoda.com/) myself I went to the login and used the database credentials I entered with PHPmyAdmin through my webhost, 6te.net. I made fake credentials as a sort of test: `vSpark123` and `ChloeGrace417`. I got the following error message:

> Database Login failed! Please make sure that the DB login credentials provided are correct
>   mysqlerror:Access denied for user 'prasanth'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   Database login failed!`.

When I went to the `register.php` in my site I got the same message.

With PHPmyAdmin it default set the database name to `619154` and I created the table inside with the name `Login` and the two columns are `Username` and `Password`.
Is it something I'm doing wrong with PHPmyAdmin or something that needs to fixed in my PHP?

Comment: Is the database on the same machine as the web files, or is it on a separate machine?

Comment: Is your server listening on port 3306? `nmap localhost`? `show grants for 'prasanth'@'%';` And which user is listening? `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` Access it on http://medievaltvg.freeoda.com/phpmyadmin/

Comment: the database is with PHPmyAdmin through 6te.net so I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know anything about changing Ports

Comment: It's kind of important to know.

Comment: I just checked and the database is on `localhost`

Comment: But user on database will show it with `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it is stays on the Login form or registration form and shows the login database failed message

Comment: I see this is free hosting "http://freeoda.com/" so do you have all data for accessing into phpmyadmin?

Comment: Why you are not try with some another better hosting or buy it? http://www.000webhost.com/

Comment: These are the privileges my webhost says I have with PHPmyAdmin Select, Insert, Update, Delete, Create, Drop, Alter, Lock_tables, Index, Create_tmp_table, References, Create_view, Show_view

Comment: I should try 000webhost.com?

Comment: looks like you are using your testing or local server mysql database username and password to connect to the server db, try finding the php connection file on your server, edit it and update the username and the password with the ones provided by your server

Comment: @razzak Wait, I;m not sure what the PHP connection file is

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have entered wrong database username or password in database connection file.

If you have forgot your password you can use following query to update it.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE User='prasanth' AND Host='localhost';
```

Comment: I know my username and password, I just don't know what or where my PHP connection file is

Answer (score 0):

You have two sets of credentials here, and you seem confused about how each of them work. The first set of credentials are what you enter on the web-based login form, and store in your database; your users enter these credentials and they are validated by your script. The second set, is the credentials your PHP script must use to connect to the MySQL server and access the database; your script sends these to the database server and they are validated by the database (MySQL) server as configured by your web host.

The error message you're getting is typical of what PHP does when a MySQL server tells it "access denied". I.e. the error relates to the *second* set of credentials, not the first (so the structure of your database is irrelevant as the error occurs before your script can access the database).

When you created the database at your webhost, you should have been given the following details: server (you've said this is `localhost`), database name (you've said this is `619154`), username, and password. You'll need to enter this information into the database connection call in your script; see the examples on [choosing a MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for details on what to look for.